# Smart cast to warning, Android Studio

Tags: android, kotlin

Tengo una duda, por el que el IDE me pone en color como verde countingPoint donde lo paso como parametro... en si el warning me dice esto:

smart cast to com.package.folder.CountingPoints ( for null call )

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

no marca error ni nada, pero visualmente me molesta que este eso de color verde subrayado.. espero me puedan orientar un poco, saludos.!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eso pasa por la condición anterior `countingPoint != null`. En lugar de hacer el chequeo de `null` de esa forma puedes hacerlo así:

```
countingPoint?.let { locationFound(it) } ?: callAnotherMethod()
```

De esta manera solo si `countingPoint` no es `null` llamará al método `locationFound` y si es null entonces llamará al método que pongas despues del operador Elvis.

Si necesitas hacer algo más que llamar a un método en caso de que `countinPoint` sea `null` entonces hazlo así:

```
countingPoint?.let { locationFound(it) } ?: run { 
    callAnotherMethod()
    // Otras instrucciones más...
}
```

Y si definitivamente no quieres cambiar el código porque te gusta más así entonces puedes desactivar todas las notificaciones como esa desde el Menú bajo la opción `File -> Settings -> Editor -> Color Scheme -> Kotlin`. Y en el recuadro que se abre buscas `Smart-casts -> Smart-cast value` y le quitas el check a `Background`.

[image: Settings: Smart-casts background color.]

Comment: Gracias, en efecto eso era, mejor usar lo que kotlin nos ofrece a desactivarlo de los settings jejej

Answer (score 0):

En realidad es una caracteristica de la IDE llamada `Smart Cast`, lo que realiza es que el compilador de `Kotlin` rastrea las condiciones internas de la expresión `if`.

Si el compilador encuentra que una variable no es nula de tipo anulable, entonces el compilador permitirá acceder a la variable.

Por ejemplo, si realizaras ùnicamente lo siguiente se provocarìa un error:

```
locationPoint(countingPoint) //* Error al compilar
```

por lo tanto necesitas realizar una validaciòn para determinar si la variable `countingPoint` tiene o no valor null para llamar la funciòn `locationPoint()`:

```
if(countingPoint != null) { // Smart Cast!
  locationPoint(countingPoint) // Correcto!
}
```

---

En realidad deberìas verlo como un beneficio que te ofrece la IDE:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

Si deseas deshabilitarlo o cambiar su color  realizalo desde los `Settings` en `Editor` de `Kotlin` :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: muchas gracias, si eso era